# Unable to start logstash in windows

Tags: logstash

I am getting the following error message when I start logstash in Windows : `Error: Could not find or load main class Stack\Elastic`

Starting logstash with the command:

```
bin\logstash -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }"
```

JDK is installed properly on my system. java -version gives the following :

```
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)
```

I am using logstash version 7.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather funny. I have a folder named ELK Stack inside which I have logstash folder. The spacing between "ELK" and "Stack" was causing me the issue even I though I properly routed to the logstash folder and fired the above command. I did not face such issues while starting elastic search and kibana.